# Extract list of words with specific character from string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string contain words, each word has its own token (eg. NN/NNP/JJ etc). I want to take specific **repeat words that contain NNP** token. My code so far:

```
import re

sentence = "Rapunzel/NNP Sheila/NNP let/VBD down/RP her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN in Yasir/NNP"

tes = re.findall(r'(\w+)/NNP', sentence)
print(tes)
```

The result of the code:

```
['Rapunzel', 'Sheila', 'Yasir']
```

As we see, there are 3 words contain NNP those are Rapunzel/NNP Sheila/NNP (appear next to each other) and Yasir/NNP (seperate by words to other NNP words). My problem is I need to sperate the word with repeat NNP and the other. My expected result is like :

```
['Rapunzel/NNP', 'Sheila/NNP'], ['Yasir/NNP']
```

What is the best way to perform this task, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need `['Rapunzel/NNP', 'Sheila/NNP'], ['Yasir/NNP']` and not `['Rapunzel', 'Sheila'], ['Yasir']`? You set a capturing group in your pattern around `\w+` - is it a "typo"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ya, I actually need to keep the token (NNP) for further process. the `\w+` is not a typo, I guess its mean to detect any letter before `/NNP `. correct me if I am wrong. thanks

Comment: I meant the parentheses. Then use Tim's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match the groups as simple strings, and then split them:

```
>>> [m.split() for m in re.findall(r"\w+/NNP(?:\s+\w+/NNP)*", sentence)]
[['Rapunzel/NNP', 'Sheila/NNP'], ['Yasir/NNP']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get very close to your expected outcome using a different capture group.

```
>>> re.findall(r'((?:\w+/NNP\s*)+)', sentence)
['Rapunzel/NNP Sheila/NNP ', 'Yasir/NNP']
```

Capture group `((?:\w+/NNP\s*)+)` will group all the `\w+/NNP` patterns together with optional spaces in between.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative without any regex. It uses [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "Rapunzel/NNP Sheila/NNP let/VBD down/RP her/PP$ long/JJ golden/JJ hair/NN in Yasir/NNP"
words = string.split()

def get_token(word):
    return word.split('/')[-1]

print([list(ws) for token, ws in groupby(words, get_token) if token == "NNP"])
# [['Rapunzel/NNP', 'Sheila/NNP'], ['Yasir/NNP']]
```